# Python interdependent class defaults

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is a completely ridiculous question, but I a missing one crucial python behaviour somewhere...

In principle I want to have some default values defined in a class, which should be totally fine to any user. However, if someone wants to change them, it should be allowed.

```
import os

class Defaults:

    # Define default directories
    main_directory = os.getcwd() + "/"
    sub_directory1 = main_directory + "Sub_directory_1/"
    sub_directory2 = main_directory + "Sub_directory_2/"

    # Define default parameters
    par1 = 10
    par2 = 20
```

The directories are used to put some output, but say, I want to specify a difference main_directory in the beginning with

```
Defaults.main_directory = /path/to/somewhere/else/
```

and the sub-directories should also change for all subsequent call accordingly when I call

```
Defaults.sub_directory1
```

The same for the parameters. I want to have some default defined which are used many times in many functions. All I want is to be able to change them in the very beginning of the script via, say,

```
Defaults.par1 = 70
```

so that throughout all other calls, this values is then changed to 70.

I tried so many things with `__init__()` but I am just not sure what I am doing wrong.

I hope you can help.
thanks

Here a real world example in the appendix:

```
import os

class Defaults:

    main_directory = os.getcwd() + "/"
    sub_dir = main_directory + "Sub1/"

print(Defaults.main_directory)
print(Defaults.sub_dir)

Defaults.main_directory = "/path/to/somewhere/"

print(Defaults.main_directory)
print(Defaults.sub_dir)
```

where for the last print statement nothing has changed...

Comment: Is the Defaults class meant to function as a singleton? If not, you probably want to get/set these values on an *instance* (e.g., self) instead of the class definition itself.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Would you have a simple example? 

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need, but a common pattern is to set various default values at the class level (`DEFAULTS` in the example below) and then to allow users to override those defaults when instantiating new objects. Here is a simplified example:

```
import os

class Fubb:

    DEFAULTS = dict(
        main_dir = '/foo/bar',
        sub_dir  = 'blah',
    )

    def __init__(self, main_dir = None, sub_dir = None):
        ds = self.DEFAULTS
        self.main_dir = main_dir or ds['main_dir']
        self.sub_dir = os.path.join(self.main_dir, sub_dir  or ds['sub_dir'])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(vars(self))

print Fubb()
print Fubb(main_dir = '/bazz')
print Fubb(main_dir = '/bazz', sub_dir = 'abc')
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for your answer. This indeed works for separate instances of the class. However, I had hoped to set the defaults one time at the beginning of my script so that they are globally available for all functions without passing any instance to them.

Comment: @HansSnah You can always modify the class-level defaults at any time. `Fubb.DEFAULTS['main_dir'] = '/whatever'`. That will affect the defaults available to all future `Fubb` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
import os

class Defaults:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_dir = os.getcwd() + '/'
        self.sub_dir = 'sub1/'
    def getPath(self):
        return self.main_dir + self.sub_dir
```

In this code, "self" refers to the instance of the class, not the class definition itself. You can see how this works at a command line session:

```
>>> d = Defaults()   # <--- create an instance of Defaults
>>> d.main_dir
'/Users/someuser/'
>>> d.sub_dir
'sub1/'
>>> d.getPath()
'/Users/someuser/sub1/'
>>> d.main_dir = '/some/other/dir/'
>>> d.getPath()
'/some/other/dir/sub1/'
```

Comment: Hey. I see that this works, but only for the instance you created there. The problem is, that I want to use the defaults project wide and I don't want to pass this default instance to all functions which use some parameters. I hoped that I could set them sort of in the background and each function has access to the new default variables.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll add a new answer to address that case.

Answer (score 0):

Changing attributes directly is not always best option. If you want `subdir` to change dynamically after you changed `main_directory`, the easiest way is to add a specific method that will change all relevant attributes so your class will look like:

```
class Default(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_directory = '/some/dir'
        self.subdir = self.main_directory + '/subdir'

    def change_dir(self, dir):
        self.main_directory = dir
        self.subdir = dir + '/subdir'
```

You may also think about using more advanced Python features like [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment to my previous answer, here's one way you could use Defaults as a singleton to store a common set of values:

```
class Defaults:
    a = 'some value'
    b = 'another value'

class Foo(Defaults):
    def combine(self):
        return ','.join([Defaults.a, Defaults.b])
```

Here's a interpreter session:

```
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f1.combine()
'some value,another value'
>>> f2.combine()
'some value,another value'
>>> Defaults.a = 'new value'
>>> f1.combine()
'new value,another value'
>>> f2.combine()
'new value,another value'
```